# Java ResourceBundle loaded from Properties file is missing base name

Tags: java, null, resourcebundle

In my program, a ResourceBundle is used for localized console output messages. The resource bundle is loaded from properties files, and currently, there is only the default locale with English messages. It is package-wise located at `klfr.sof.SOFMessages` (i.e. file `src/klfr/sof/SOFMessages.properties`). This resource bundle can without a problem be located and loaded with a single line like:

```java
ResourceBundle.getBundle("klfr.sof.SOFMessages");
```

For most purposes and most of my project, I just used this bundle directly and it never posed a problem. Locales seem to work normally, too.

However, for expanding the localization to logging, I want to attach the resource bundle to the `java.util.logging` system. Then, I could use message keys in my log calls, etc. For this purpose, I use this code:

```java
ResourceBundle R = ResourceBundle.getBundle("klfr.sof.SOFMessages");
Logger.getLogger("").setResourceBundle(R);
```

But this throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource bundle must have a name
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.setResourceBundle(Logger.java:2320)
        at <line with setResourceBundle()>
```

This seemed very weird to me. The "name" that the exception mentions is the base name of the resource bundle, as retrieved by `getBaseBundleName()`. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBaseBundleName()) states:

> Returns the base name of this bundle, if known, or null if unknown. If not null, then this is the value of the baseName parameter that was passed to the ResourceBundle.getBundle(...) method when the resource bundle was loaded.

As I stated, I did use `getBundle` to load this resource bundle successfully. I did provide a base name. And the base name is now gone. I called `getBaseBundleName()` myself after loading the RB and it is null.

Because I could not believe this, I dug into the Java source code that loads `PropertyResourceBundle`s, including debugging the above lines and stepping deep into the library call stack, and tracking the bundle objects that were created. I found out that the `name` attribute, returned by `getBaseBundleName()`, isn't ever set by any code that runs in my case (Properties file, small parent chains, module class loader, and similar defaults).

So what am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my code or Java itself? The `java --version` states:

```
openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Just a side note: The root logger seems to be the logger with empty string name (not the `getGlobal()` thing). It works for the "root" purpose in all other things like log handlers, logging levels etc., so I never questioned it.

Comment: Strange.  I am not seeing any of this behavior.  ResourceBundle.getBundle always returns an instance which has a non-null name for me, when loading from a properties file.  By any chance is klfr/sof/SOFMessages.properties located in a different module?

Comment: No, it isn't, it's even the same package.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `R.getBaseBundleName()` return?

Comment: @VGR null as well. In the real code, R is a constant (public static final) and therefore probably loaded at clinit

Comment: Does the problem occur if R is defined as a non-static public final field?  I’m wondering if perhaps some information isn’t available at class loading time.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. If that is of any help: It all worked like a charm until I moved the code and the properties file into a module. Now I'm getting the same exception as you.

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same problem that `getBaseBundleName()` returns `null`. Also because bundle properties file is located in module (though the same module and package as the code loading it). IMHO this is a bug in JDK. Created a workaround for my problem...